# OpenNI Intrinsic and Extrinsic calibration

Tags: computer-vision, openni, 3d-reconstruction

How would one extract the components of the intrinsic and extrinsic calibration parameters from OpenNI for a device such as the PrimeSense?

After some searching I only seem to find how to do it through ROS, but it is not clear how it would be done with just OpenNI.

Comment: Is this for matching depth and color data ?

Comment: Intrinsics are for the sensor calibrations, for projection etc, extrinsics are the calibration params between the sensors and the world.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Intrinsic_parameters